# How to send list of Python UUIDs into csql query using cassandra_driver for Python

Tags: python, cassandra

I'm trying to pass a python list of UUIDs to CSQL query...but the query evaluates to be like below..and it fails at cassandra.

```
select  json *  from users where user_id in [UUID('f3cbb11a-08e6-11e9-805c-507b9dd95453'), UUID('f3c45e1d-08e6-11e9-8441-507b9dd95453')] ALLOW FILTERING

sess=self.cass.getConnection()
query ="select  json *  from users where user_id in {} ALLOW FILTERING".format(user_ids)
sess.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

lets say that you have a list of uuids:

```
uuids = [UUID('f3cbb11a-08e6-11e9-805c-507b9dd95453'), UUID('f3c45e1d-08e6-11e9-8441-507b9dd95453')]
```

Based on [documentation](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html#passing-parameters-to-cql-queries) you have to create the query template first:

```
query = '''
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE user_id IN ({}) 
ALLOW FILTERING'''.format(','.join('%s' for _ in uuids))
print(query)

SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE user_id IN (%s,%s) 
ALLOW FILTERING
```

and then execute the query:

```
session.execute(query, uuids)
```